# can there be a normal wallet that is equivalent to a multisig wallet?

Tags: multi-signature

for a normal wallet : if you own the private key you own the money
can we say that the multisig wallet is just a normal wallet which the private key was derived from others wallets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the multisig wallet is just a normal wallet which the private key was derived from others wallets

That's pretty much exactly what it is. A multisig address lists the public keys that are allowed to spend the coins, and how many members of the group must sign (for instance, you can require 2 of 3 signatures). As long as enough private keys are accessible, the funds can be moved.

Comment: so in this case , even if you have a multisig wallet that require many people to sign , there is still a very small propability that someone by chance find a private key for a normal wallet which is nothing but your multisig wallet , right

Comment: No, multisig wallets are p2sh wallets, private key backed wallets are p2pkh. Even if you find a hash collision, the script is different. You will need to find a collision for the redeem script hash, and your colliding redeem script must also be valid